# The office(U.S) dialogue

Tags: meaning

here is the dialogue from "the office season 9." and I totally don't understand what it means. Please help me. I don't know the Dwight's line.

> Pam: That sucked. He didn’t apologize. There’s no talking to that guy.
>
> **Dwight: Oh, your little feelings party didn’t work out, huh? Who won the hugging contest? No, let me guess, everyone tied for first.**
>
> Pam: We should just take him down.

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand? Note that “party” and “contest” may not be an actual party and a contest (respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Dwight is being condescending here. He is implying that Pam has a ridiculously naïve view of the world. The phrase:

> Who won the hugging contest? No, let me guess, everyone tied for first.

Implies that they had a "hugging contest" which would be kind of childish and, to Dwight's ultra-rational persona, ridiculous. "Everyone tied for first" implies that even in something as low-stakes as a "hugging contest," Pam couldn't be tough enough to pick winners and losers, so just said "everyone won!"